# Spark Standalone CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:74 - Driver * disassociated! Shutting down

Tags: apache-spark

I have seen a similar issue in the below post and trying to increase my memory overhead in standalone cluster but have not see any parameter for this in spark 1.6.0

[Why spark application fail with "executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver Disassociated"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967500/why-spark-application-fail-with-executor-coarsegrainedexecutorbackend-driver-d)

Is there a default parameter that i can use to increase the memory overHead for Standalone cluster like **spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead**??

Comment: I am also getting the same error.

Comment: This happens if the Spark Driver fails (memory issue, node restart etc.), and [by default it is not fault-tolerant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618464/what-happens-if-the-driver-program-crashes). `spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead` param can help with memory based issues though.

Comment: @springstarter [--supervise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317635/sparkexecutor-coarsegrainedexecutorbackend-driver-disassociated-disassociated/43539999#43539999) can address if you're using Standalone cluster.